# How to get the DST gap and overlap?

Tags: java, dst, zoneddatetime, java-time

`ZonedDateTime` doesn't seem to allow to detect if the date given is in a DST gap or overlap. The docs say for the `of` method (creating a `ZonedDateTime`):

> In the case of an overlap, when clocks are set back, there are two
>   valid offsets. This method uses the earlier offset typically
>   corresponding to "summer".
>
> In the case of a gap, when clocks jump forward, there is no valid
>   offset. Instead, the local date-time is adjusted to be later by the
>   length of the gap.

^ as read above, this method will just return a value but will not allow me to know if a DST gap or overlap occurs.

I would like to know if the date provided is in a gap or overlap, and have the starting date and ending date of the gap or overlap.

For example:

"1920-09-01 00:10" for time zone "Africa/Accra" is in a **DST gap**.
The gap is **from "1920-09-01 00:00:00+00:00" to "1920-09-01 00:20:00+00:20"**.

"1920-12-30 23:50" for time zone "Africa/Accra" is in a **DST overlap**.
The overlap concerns the periods:
**"1920-12-30 23:40:00+00:20" to "1920-12-31 00:00:00+00:20" and

"1920-12-30 23:40:00+00:00" to "1920-12-31 00:00:00+00:00"**

How can I get these dates in case of a gap or overlap as in the examples above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is physically possible to create a `ZonedDateTime` that is in a gap transition, because the local date times that a gap transition skips over are technically "non-existent", and `ZonedDateTime` is quite strict about this. Depending on your method, it will either throw an exception or adjust to a time that exists.

You should do this check with `LocalDateTime`s, not `ZonedDateTime`s.

`ZoneRules` has this very convenient method called [`getTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getTransition-java.time.LocalDateTime-) that takes a `LocalDateTime` and gives you a `ZoneOffsetTransition`, which represents a gap/overlap transition, or `null` if that date time doesn't have a transition. Example:

```
System.out.println(ZoneId.of("Africa/Accra").getRules()
                    .getTransition(LocalDateTime.of(1920, 9, 1, 00, 10)));
```

Output:

```
Transition[Gap at 1920-09-01T00:00Z to +00:20]
```

You can then get all the information you want (start, end, offset before, offset after, gap/overlap etc) from the `ZoneOffsetTransition` object.

Comment: A ZoneOffsetTransition actually has `isGap` and `isOverlap` methods, in fact.